# accessing a general javascript object property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have setup this js object:

```
 var tableTypes = {
        "stockRcmnd":{
            "name":"stockRcmnd",
            "columns": ['1','2', '3']
        }, 
        "stockChange":{
            "name":"stockChange",
            "columns": ['4','5', '6']
        }
    };
```

now, I want to get the columns , dynamically:

```
property = "stockChange";

columns = tableTypes.{property}.columns;

property = "stockRcmnd";

columns = tableTypes.{property}.columns;
```

**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/opmaster/6yS4q/1/) is a jsfiddle;**

any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object properties can also be accessed like this in JavaScript:

`tableTypes[property].columns`

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
   tableTypes['stockRcmnd'].name
```